# Automated metatagging for images containing text

Tags: image-processing, web-services, ocr, image-recognition, metadata

While ImageNet (image-net.org) seems to be pursuing a more large-scale purpose of visual recognition of a very diverse set of images containing various complex objects, OCR tools are more straight forward and mainly deal with character recognition of text content.

Annotation is the final stage of any recognition process and can include metatagging. If an image contains only plain text or annotated figures,  then each recognized word must be checked against an external dictionary to ensure validity, whereas a combination of words must be checked for consistency (e.g. by a search query in Google). Tags can be then assigned automatically based on the list of recognized words.

I wonder if there are any free solutions or web services doing both things in a fully automated consecutive manner

1. OCR and
2. exiftool metatagging

for images with text content?